# how to use document fields in query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to choose documents where `from < now` and `to > (now + delay)`, where from, to and delay is document fields. Now is my variable.
something like that

```
{
  from: {$gte: now},
  to: {$lte: now + $delay}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.find({
    "from":{
        $gte: now
    },
    $expr:{
        $lte:["$to", { $sum: ["$delay", now] }]
    }
}).pretty()
```

```
var now = 2;
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7645ab14e02904fe680e12"),
    "from" : 2,
    "to" : 4,
    "delay" : 2
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7645ab14e02904fe680e13"),
    "from" : 2,
    "to" : 10,
    "delay" : 2
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7645ab14e02904fe680e14"),
    "from" : 6,
    "to" : 10,
    "delay" : 2
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7645ab14e02904fe680e12"),
    "from" : 2,
    "to" : 4,
    "delay" : 2
}
```

Comment: Cool, but seems like I got lower version of mongodb where `$expr` is not supported

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `$expr` you might consider [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where).

**NOTE**: `$where` has a [performance cost](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations).

Example:

```
db.collection.find({
    $where: function () {
        return this.to > (now + this.delay);
    }
});
```

`this` refers to the current document. You can also you `obj` to reference it.